# Python custom module not found, but path is in PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables, python-module

I searched for a similar question, but none of the solutions I've found have solved my problem.

I'm trying to use a local module as a python library, and I want to be able to import it everywhere when using python. I'm using a Mac OS Ventura and python 3.9.13.

The module is in the following folder structure:

```
TestLibrary
├──__init__.py
└──test_library_1.py
```

I've set the env variable as follows, in the .zshrc file in the user folder:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/my_user/path_to_folder/TestLibrary"
```

The variable seems ok, as within python, printing sys.path gives this result:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/my_user/path_to_folder/TestLibrary', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Users/my_user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

But if I try to import:

```
>>> import TestLibrary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TestLibrary'
```

Same happens if I try `from TestLibrary import test_library`

I have always worked with Windows and I'm still getting used to a Mac, so I don't know if I'm setting the env variable wrong or is anything wrong with the module.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to `import TestLibrary`, you should add the parent directory `/Users/my_user/path_to_folder` to your `PYTHONPATH`, not the directory containing the module.

Comment: Can't you just move it to the `Lib` folder in python directory?

Comment: @tripleee that was the solution!